# Getting Web Service to Authenticate using Network Credentials VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, web, service

the following VB.net code is working to authenticate to a web service - and it works great however i am having to use default network Credentials ( the logged in user the code runs under )

I would like to pass network Creds to the web service and the following should work but does not. This is the working code using default credentials.

```
    Dim URL As String = "http://server/MBSDKService/MsgSDK.asmx?WSDL"
    Dim myService As New LANDeskMBDSK.MBSDK
    myService.Url = URL
    Dim CredCache As New System.Net.CredentialCache
    myService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
```

This is what i want to work but does not...

```
    Dim URL As String = "http://server/MBSDKService/MsgSDK.asmx?WSDL"
    Dim myService As New LANDeskMBDSK.MBSDK
    myService.Url = URL
    Dim Cred As New System.Net.NetworkCredential("domain\user", "password")
    Dim CredCache As New System.Net.CredentialCache
    CredCache.Add(New Uri(myService.Url), "Basic", Cred)
    myService.Credentials = CredCache
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

The rest of the code works perfectly so it is a case of what i have to add to the above to get it to work like the default credentials do.

Thanks!

Thanks to George this is the solution...

```
    Dim URL As String = "http://server/MBSDKService/MsgSDK.asmx?WSDL"
    Dim myService As New LANDeskMBDSK.MBSDK
    myService.Url = URL
    Dim Cred As New System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password")
    Dim CredCache As New System.Net.CredentialCache
    CredCache.Add(New Uri(myService.Url), "Basic", Cred)
    myService.Credentials = Cred
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try any of these:

```
Dim Cred As New System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain")

Dim Cred As New System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password")
```

Whats the actual error message?

EDIT:

This seems to be working:

```
myService.Credentials = Cred
```

Comment: No they dont work - tried that. The error is 'The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized' its not passing the network creds correctly.

Comment: i read somewhere about creating a class and adding quite a bit of code to get this working just cant find where!

Comment: Try removing CredCache completely and use myService.Credentials = Cred

Comment: Is this the solution u were talking about? http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?641942-RESOLVED-The-request-failed-with-HTTP-status-401-Unauthorized

Comment: Yeah that was the one... however removing the CredCache worked :) So the working solution is...now posted above. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Do you need to have `Dim CredCache...` and `CredCache.Add`? Will it work without those 2 lines?